# How to fill class members from file

Tags: c#, deserialization

I want to fill class members with the values from a file.
I'm creating this file, so I can choose the formatting as I want. I thought that it should be like this to be easy to read:

```
name,value
name,value
etc.
```

I've got class "Car" with members like "Car.a", "Car.b" etc.
For example:

```
a,5
```

It should give me

```
Car.a = 5;
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: You should use something that exists and does this already like XML, JSON, etc instead of trying to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: It will most likely be easier to use some standard serialization like json or xml. Why do you prefer the format you describe in the question?

Comment: It's not that I prefer this, that's the idea I've got. If there is another way to do this, I will be more than happy to know. :)

Comment: If you convert your data into a JSON format, you can put the values into your `Car` class in one line of code with `Newtonsoft`. You won't need to do any manual mapping.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt656691.aspx) to do that. Similar to what `XmlSerializer` does:

- parse the property name and value
- determine the type of the property
- convert the string value to your property's type
- assign the value

This example works for most basic data types:

```
private void AssignProperty(object obj, string propertyName, string propertyValue)
{
    PropertyInfo property = obj.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
    property.SetValue(obj, Convert.ChangeType(propertyValue, property.PropertyType), null);
}
```

[See it in action on dotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5o3Ak5)

You can of course build your own `Deserializer` if you need to use this format more often:

```
public class StringLinesDeserializer<T> where T : new()
{
    public T Deserialize(string[] assignments)
    {
        T result = new T();

        foreach (string assignment in assignments)
        {
            int commaPos = assignment.IndexOf(',');
            string propertyName = assignment.Substring(0, commaPos);
            string propertyValue = assignment.Substring(commaPos + 1);

            AssignProperty(result, propertyName, propertyValue);
        }

        return result;
    }

    private void AssignProperty(object obj, string propertyName, string propertyValue)
    {
        PropertyInfo property = obj.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
        property.SetValue(obj, Convert.ChangeType(propertyValue, property.PropertyType), null);
    }
}
```

Could be used like this:

```
string[] assignments = new string[]{"a,5","b,6"};
StringLinesDeserializer<Car> deserializer = new StringLinesDeserializer<Car>();
Car newCar = deserializer.Deserialize(assignments);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're open to other ways of doing this I suggest using something like [Json.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to serialize/deserialize your objects. Here's a short example:

```
Car car = new Car { a = 10, name = "Golf" };
var str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(car);
```

`str` will contain a serialized version of your Car object in json format that looks like this:

```
{"a":10,"name":"Golf"}
```

And if you want to recreate your object back from that JSON string then use this:

```
Car deserializedCar = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Car>(str);
```

[Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YdMh1o)

If you'd rather use XML:

```
var car = new Car { name = "Hellcat", a = 10 };
var serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(Car));
string carXml = null;
using (var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
{
    serializer.Serialize(ms, car);
    carXml = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
}
```

`carXml` will contain the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Car xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <a>10</a>
  <name>Hellcat</name>
</Car>
```

Answer (score 0):

By following text file content:

> a,20
>   b,14

If you defined `Car` class as following:

```
public class Car
{
    public object a { get; set; }
    public object b { get; set; }
}
```

Try following method:

```
private Car GetCarFromFile(string strFilePath)
{
    var lstCarFile = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(strFilePath);

    var car = new Car();
    foreach (var c in lstCarFile)
    {
        var name = c.Split(',')[0].Trim();
        var value = c.Split(',')[1].Trim();

        car.GetType().GetProperty(name).SetValue(car, value, null);
    }

    return car;
}
```

To call the mentioned method simply pass path parameter of text file:

```
var car = GetCarFromFile("D:/CarMembersValue.txt");
```